# Is it possible to change partitionkey on azure table entities?

Tags: openid, azure-table-storage

On my website the user will log in using Open ID and I'll store the claimed identifier as an entity in Azure Tables using a hash of the claimed identifier as the partition key.

The work items that the user then creates on the site are also stored in Azure Tables using the same hash for the partition key. This seemed useful from a performance point since one user will always query their own partition key.

But before I paint myself into a corner, how can I make it possible for the user to change their open id provider and the claimed identifier? Because if their claimed id changes, the hash for the partition key has to change. And I can't change it can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the partition key for a table, as it is how entities are identified.

You will need to add a new entity and delete the old one.

You could try using another partition key.